# Why doesn't the touch event arrive at my UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have some nested views like this:

First, there is an big UIView. Inside this, there is another UIView. And inside this, there is an MyNiceButtons class that inherits from UIView. So I have:

UIView > UIView > MyNiceButtons (= an UIView).

In detail, the  UIView creates an UIImageView and adds it as a child view to itself, which represents an graphical button. So inside the MyNiceButtons class implementation, I have this code to handle a touch event on the fake button image:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; // i just need single touches

    // just to see which view is affected
    UIView *tview = [touch view];
    CGRect rect = tview.frame;
    rect.origin.x = rect.origin.x + 20.0f;
    tview.frame = rect;
    [tview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];

    if ([touch view] == self.fakeButtonImageView) {
        NSLog(@"touch on fake button detected");
    }
}
```

All views in the hierarchy have userInteractionEnabled=YES. The touch arrives at the first view in the hierarchy (the parent of the parent).

```
UIView *tview = [touch view];
```

This returns just the parent of the parent, but not the UIImageView where the user actually tapped on.

What's the trick to recognize if the touch was on the button UIImageView?

Comment: Is MyNiceButtons a UIImageView subclass or have a UIImageView

Comment: An UIView "A" contains an UIView "B", which contains an UIImageView. UIView "B" has the touch-detection code and asks if it happened on the UIImageView.

Answer (score 2):

I would first suggest that you take a good look at what you can do with a Custom-type UIButton (can set images for various states). 95% of the time, this should address your needs.

If you have some other need, I can help you debug w/ hitTest, etc.

Comment: You're right about the UIButton, but for practise I want to know what's wrong here. It should actually work...